# Can we update the APK on Google Play Store with out changing the APP Version

Tags: java, android, sqlite, apk, google-play

Can anyone let me know, Can I replace the APK uploaded to Google Play Store, with out changing the App version.

Basically I have uploaded the app with version 1.0 yesterday, and today I want to reupload the APK with some important fix, and do not want to change the version.

Comment: Venkat, you should accept an answer to close the question... unless you want further clarification.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You **cannot** update an existing app w/o changing its *version code*. Each time you update your app, you should increment its version code by 1. The version code is not externally visible to the user, and is used only as a means of versioning your application.

You **can** update an existing app w/o changing its *version name*. The version name is what the user will see on Google Play (i.e. version 1.10, 2.08, etc.), and has nothing to do with the actual version number of your application (it can be anything you want).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, Can you please elaborate on "Version code" and "Version name".

Comment: try this link brief explanation http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't upload same version apk in Android market.

Answer (score 1):

There are two type of app version versionCode and versionName. For updating the apk in play store versionCode should be incremented by one from the previous value and versionName is not  mandatory to change. It is up to you but keep in mind only the external user  can see versionName  so if you are updating the apk it is recommendated to change the versionName.

Answer (score -1):

FWIW, I was able to upload an APK file to Googe Play without increasing the version number.

1)  I uploaded version 100 (1.0.0) a couple of days ago.

2)  I generated a new APK with version 100 (1.0.0), and it uploaded without any problems.

Please note, however, in my case, the app is in Draft state.  It has not been published yet.  Once published, I wouldn't replace it with a build that has the very same version number (and besides, it probably won't be accepted by Google Play then.)

As a side note, I tried uploading version 10 (1.0), and Google Play would not accept it stating I need to increase the version number.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this with a trick.

My Google play speaks italian so try to understand...Click on `go back to old site design`, then go inside your app details and click ok `File APK` tab on top.

Now in `File APK` page old version, click on `go to advanced version`, and click on `deactivate`.

**IMPORTANT**: do not click on `delete` after clicking `deactivate` or your app will be permanently deleted and you will compile again the store details (description, images, icon, etc).

Now go back to new style site and you will not find any apk uploaded and you can provide a new version without increase version number.

My apk wasn't released when i did this trick.