# How to upload same apk file in playstore

Tags: android, apk

I have uploaded an apk file in play store and publish but after publish i have found some error in app. After that i have unpublished app and fix the error but after fixing my app i'm trying to re-upload the apk file but it cannot upload and send the message"*please upload newer version of code*".

So please help me how to upload  that apk file into the play store.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we update the APK on Google Play Store with out changing the APP Version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908432/can-we-update-the-apk-on-google-play-store-with-out-changing-the-app-version)

Comment: Change versionCode and versionName inside **build.gradle**

Answer (score 5):

Please change your version code , version name and try again. Either in your manifest file or build.gradle.

```
 live {
            minSdkVersion 19
            applicationId 'your package name'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.liveSigning
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 68 // Change Here
            versionName '2.3.1'
            resConfigs "en"
        }
```

Comment: @Charuka ya but still it's a good practice to change a version name when you upload a new APK.

Comment: You need to upgrade your for ex. versionCode 1 change by  2 in manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

change the version code and version name